# Python coding question

Tags: python, finance

I have a question regarding how to code the logic below in python:

I have one reference table containing  information what should be inside each different bucket, 1 would indicate it should contain and 0 would indicate it should not contain:

[image]

Than I have to add additional columns in the end of the following table to check if the bucket is containing the right material.
[image]

in the end what i want is something that checkes each trade like below:
[image]

any ideas?

Thanks!